# Sharing images across projects in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I'd like to use the same images in multiple device apps in Xamarin.

I have a PCL core library and have started using MVVMCross.
What's the best approach to accomplish this? Can I embed them as a resource in the Core library and access it in my Andriod/iOs project, or is it better to use add as link?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can in theory embed these as binary resources in the PCL project and can then access them as `byte[]` via `GetResourceStream` and from there can then get them decoded in your UI projects. This would require some work to setup and would make it impossible to use the images in the xib editor, in the android XML, etc

More easily, you can also share these image files using 'Add as link' and then allow each individual platform to optimize and package the files - each platform is good at this - eg Android with its different dpi drawable folders and IOS with its 2x image packaging. This technique also works well with the xib and XML designers.

However, in practice I generally find I don't share these image files between projects - instead on most commercial projects, the PhotoShop guys insist on giving me icons, dividers, and other chrome images which are unique to each platform.