# Xamarin: How to load image from iOS library project

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uiimage, mvvmcross

I have a Xamarin Project styled with MvvmCross. There are Subprojects:

- Core (PCL)
- ViewModel (PCL)
- iOS (Executable)

If i add an image to my iOS project (Resoureces/Images/test_image.png), then i can load it with this code:

```
UIImage image = UIImage.FromBundle("Images/test_icon.png");
```

Now, i want to use a new Subproject

- Controls (iOS Library)

This library should load an image. I added an image to Controls (Resoureces/Images/test_image.png)

But i can not load this image in Controls proj.

My Question: How to load images from iOS libraries?

```
    public class MyButton : UIButton
    {
        public MyButton () : base()
        {
            Initialize ();
        }

        void Initialize()
        {
            // load image from bundle
            UIImage image = UIImage.FromBundle("Images/test_icon.png");
            // image is null
            this.SetImage (image, UIControlState.Normal);
        }
    }
```

and the ViewController class is :

```
    public partial class FirstView : MvxViewController
    {
        public FirstView () : base ("FirstView", null)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            // load image from bundle
//          UIImage image = UIImage.FromBundle("Images/test_icon.png");
//          image is not null if added in iOS Proj
//          this.imageView.Image = image;

            MyButton button = new MyButton ();

            View.Add (button);

            View.AddConstraint (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (button, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, 1, 10));
            View.AddConstraint (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (button, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1, 74));
            View.AddConstraint (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (button, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, null, NSLayoutAttribute.NoAttribute, 0, 64)); 
            View.AddConstraint (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (button, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, null, NSLayoutAttribute.NoAttribute, 0, 64)); 
        }
    }
```

[image]

Here is full proj: https://bitbucket.org/ww_wschaefer/xamarin-first-crossover-app/overview

Comment: You cant use from Bundle unless its available as bundeled resource, I think you would be better of using `UIImage.FromFile("Images/test_icon.png")`. You should also have a look at this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18130779/1155650).

Comment: I can't belive, the solution is so easy, thanks Rohit.

Comment: glad your problem was solved. I have added the explanation if you are interested.

Comment: If you don't mind please do accept the answer if it solved your problem, so that it would be helpful for others as well. @iOSfleer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A little explanation on my comment.

You have to change

```
UIImage image = UIImage.FromBundle("Images/test_icon.png");
```

to

```
UIImage image = UIImage.FromFile("Images/test_icon.png");
```

As the image is not added as bundled resource.

The `UIImage.FromFile()` method loads the image asynchronously. **It also allows the application to load the image from an external location**.

Unlike the `UIImage.FromFile()` method, the `UIImage.FromBundle()` method is a blocking call and **only loads images from within the application bundle**. However, it caches the images after loading it.

For further understanding have a look at the book - [Developing C# Apps for iPhone and iPad using MonoTouch](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=ZheAQ87aAcIC&pg=PA100&lpg=PA100&dq=UIImage.FromBundle%20versus%20UIImage.FromFile&source=bl&ots=rpdO7nc26p&sig=SW3oZ7bKiKgBj_4UTOt-3GaVJ-o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CGAQ6AEwCGoVChMI1sz25tz2xwIV1pCOCh3ANgsX#v=onepage&q=UIImage.FromBundle%20versus%20UIImage.FromFile&f=false)

Comment: @iOSfleer - Can you please confirm if this is the solution that worked for you?