# UIImage Bundle returns nil in iOS 11 / XCode 9

Tags: iphone, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have the following project setup:

- MyLibraryClass - Class that contains generic code including all my images. (Class library in other words)
- MyBrandedClass - Main class that runs the app and has specific images that are not generic (has a reference to Library class' assembly)

In **iOS 10 / XCode 8**, I referenced all my images inside the Library class by using `UIImage.FromBundle(myImageName)`

After updating to **iOS 11 / XCode 9**, that same line returns nil. As an experiment I moved all my image resources from my Library class to the Branded class and the images were loaded properly. Did Apple change the way bundle resources are compiled from iOS 10 - iOS 11 (or Xcode 8 - 9)?

I am using the version **Xamarin iOS 11.3.0.47** & **Xamarin 4.1.10.38** on VS 2017. The problem only arised when I updated **Xamarin** so I am not sure whether it was this the cause or the **Xcode** update.

I found this [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=34762) that was created for **Xamarin** describing exactly what I have.

Is there a clean way to reference my images in my BrandedClass or am I forced to copy all my image assets to that project?

Comment: Try to use `FromFile` instead of `FromBundle`  maybe helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32566167/xamarin-how-to-load-image-from-ios-library-project

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I am still receiving a null. I am not sure if this is the reason but my folder structure for the images are a bit different from the one in the link. I have a Resources folder with a sub folder Images.xcassets. Inside the Images folder are my .imageset folders for each image. Those contain the Content.json and specific images for each device size.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of your project folder , so that i can try to reproduce your issue.